# How to change CSS float value through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using div with CSS value `float: right;`. I would like to change that by using JavaScript to change float attribute to left using on click function.

So I'm using click event listener:

```
document.getElementById("english").addEventListener("click", function isEnglish(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('tab').style.cssFloat = "left";
});
```

but I fail to change float direction, the element stays in the same place. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/RwNLZrj)

How can I change float direction using JavaScript?

Comment: Why “cssFloat”? And not just “float”?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Comment: accept/upvote the answer if it helped, check [When Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('tab')` returns a list of elements to you may have to iterate over it.

The js property for float is `float` instead of `ccsFloat` you used in your code.

```js
document.getElementById("english").addEventListener("click", function isEnglish(){
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tab')).forEach(v => {
        v.style.float = "left";
    });
});
```

```css
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<p class="tab">a</p>
<p class="tab">b</p>
<p class="tab">c</p>
<p class="tab">d</p>
<p class="tab">e</p>

<button id="english">english</button>
```